# How do I change the command of delete key of nemo file manager?

Tags: debian, cinnamon, gnu, nemo

I use debian with cinnamon (desktop environment). If I want to delete file on nemo file manager I have to select file with mouse then I have to press delete key to delete file.

I would like to change this command of delete key with truncate (with selected file) "sudo truncate -s0 (selected file)"

How can I do that?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are asking for

Comment: It sounds like "I want pressing the delete key to truncate the selected file instead of unlinking it".

Comment: @MichaelHomer  Thats right. Now, if I selected a file with mouse on nemo file manager the file will be deleted. I want to change this command with "truncate -s0" file selected!

Comment: @mashuptwice I want to change this command. Now the delete key on nemo delete file. I want to change this with this command "truncate -s0" of selected file.

Comment: I answered your literal question in my answer (sorry, you can't). However, what you want to do is rather surprising; why would you want to truncate files from a file manager? What necessitates this functionality? Maybe we have a solution for the problem that prompted you to ask this!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Why can't I change nemo shortcut??? I want to truncate files before delete them. I want it for biggest security.If truncate files it is  unrecoverable.

Comment: @user14795102 because nemo is not programmed in a way that let's you do that. Just like you can't rewire your car to take a sharp right turn when you hold the steering wheel centered.

Comment: truncating before deletion introduces exactly **no** security at all. Not a single bit. Not at all. The file system will look exactly the same on the disk. "If truncate files it is unrecoverable." is plain and simply wrong. Truncating before deletion has no effect whatsoever. Deletion and truncation both unassign the extents used by data on the storage medium from the file/inode.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Why do you put minus in my question? I don't undersand why trruncate is not safe. After truncate files are  unrecoverable , so nobody see the content of file. Can you tell what is good practice for you for files deletion? I already have full encrypt my system.

Comment: truncation has, as I wrote, absolutely no effect that deletion would not already have. You seem to be mistaken about what truncation does.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do that?

Not at all (or, rather: you'd need to change a rather central functionality in the nemo source code, build the software, and make it replace the `nemo` from your debian package so that things still work. I.e., you can't do it with nemo, but you could author a fork of nemo that does that.)

nemo doesn't support that. (I'd argue that's a good thing, in the sense that your desired functionality is rarely needed and surprising. The key is labeled "del", not "truncate".) Atop of it being impossible to replace the "remove this file" functionality, you also want to do things using `sudo` which opens another can of worms where you first need to gain sudo privileges before being able to do this.

You can write a nemo plugin that you could run from the context menu, instead, or use "copy to clipboard <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>" functionality to copy the marked file names to the clipboard and then paste that into a terminal after `truncate -s0` .

Comment: I tried to make a plugin inside nemo actions folders with no luck. Would you like to help me how can I do that?

Comment: @user14795102 I'd love to, but I currently don't have the time. If it helps, I only wrote one, and that was by copying an existing one and modifying it.

Comment: Where have you nemo action scripts?